# SQL Server - Vertica Connection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, odbc, vertica, external-tables

I need to query a hp vertica database from SQL Server stored procedure. It is a join query and If I use linked server, it is going to fire as 2 separate selects and join it in the SQL Server . Is there any way I can use ODBC to fire the join query to Vertica from TSQL and get the processed result set back into an SQL table.?
Any other approach to suggest to achieve this ?

Comment: 1. Create a [linked server](http://vertica.tips/2013/10/30/creating-a-linked-server-from-sql-server/) to Vertica 2. Pull data into a temp table

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52521/create-linked-server-to-vertica

Comment: Not exactly. I did connect linked server and it is working great. The problem is if I execute a query joining 2 tables in vertica(70 million record and 1 million record) it doesnt pull up fast because , it seems the join process is not happening in Vertica instead it pulls both tables separately and do the join in SQL Server which doesnt helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use `OPENQUERY` syntax in SQL Server, to get the full query sent to Vertica for execution there...  There are other possibilities, but we'd need much more detail about what you have in play (especially but not only your current query) to usefully discuss them.

Comment: Some reason I didnt think of OPENQUERY. Thank you very much.